# Generar un JSON a partir de datos Excel en VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, macros

Tengo un inconveniente, el siguiente es: Generar un archivo .txt Json con valores de un archivo Excel en macros.

Adjunto código

Código donde obtengo los datos de 2 columnas Excel, estos están agrupados en una matrix tanto como  palabras de referencia como valores (Ejm. Impuesto = 20.00)

```
Sub macro_retenciones()
Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim myS As String
      
ultimaFila = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
j = 2
Dim arregloNombreColumna() As String
Dim cantidadRg As Long
cantidadRg = 2

ReDim Preserve arregloNombreColumna(1)
    
For i = 2 To ultimaFila

myS = Cells(i, 4).Value

If Len(myS) > 0 And myS <> "Monto" And InStr(myS, "Empleados") = 0 Then
    
    If is_in_array(myS, arregloNombreColumna) = False Then
    
    ReDim Preserve arregloNombreColumna(cantidadRg + 1)
    
    arregloNombreColumna(cantidadRg - 2) = myS
        
    cantidadRg = cantidadRg + 1

    End If
    
End If
Next i


Dim Matrixalores() As String
ReDim Preserve Matrixalores(2, 1)

Dim strNombreColumna As String
Dim intIX As Long
Dim intIndiceContenido As Long
intIndiceContenido = 0
  
 For i = 2 To ultimaFila
 
  strNombreColumna = Cells(i, 4).Value
  myS = Cells(i, 5).Value
  
  If Len(myS) > 0 And InStr(myS, "Retenciones") = 0 Then
  
  ReDim Preserve Matrixalores(2, intIndiceContenido)
  
  intIX = index_in_array(strNombreColumna, arregloNombreColumna)
  
  Matrixalores(0, intIndiceContenido) = intIX
  Matrixalores(1, intIndiceContenido) = myS
  
  intIndiceContenido = intIndiceContenido + 1
             
  End If
  
Next i

Dim x As String

x = "3"
```

Este código me genera 2 matrices, una que se llama arregloColumnaNombre y otra Matrixalores a partir de estas 2 matrices requiero que se pueda generar un archivo Json que pueda tener por ejemplo, {valor_1:[{"Titulo1":"valor1","Titulo2":"Valor2"}]} encontré algunas referencias, no se si se utiliza alguna librería o si dentro de macros tiene alguna funcionalidad para Json.

Gracias de antemano
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que montar tú mismo el formato que necesitas (json en tu caso) pues Excel no tiene ninguna herramienta para hacer lo que pides.

Si que hay gente que ha desarrollado su propia macro para convertir datos a JSON. Por ejemplo este código sacado de http://www.excelvbamacros.in/2015/01/export-range-in-jason-format.html transforma un rango a json:

```
Sub export_in_json_format()

    Dim fs As Object
    Dim jsonfile
    Dim rangetoexport As Range
    Dim rowcounter As Long
    Dim columncounter As Long
    Dim linedata As String
    
    ' change range here
    Set rangetoexport = Sheet1.Range("a1:d8")
    
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' change dir here
    
    Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\xx\Desktop\" & "jsondata.json", True)
    
    linedata = "{""Output"": ["
    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
    For rowcounter = 2 To rangetoexport.Rows.Count
        linedata = ""
        For columncounter = 1 To rangetoexport.Columns.Count
            linedata = linedata & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(1, columncounter) & """" & ":" & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter) & """" & ","
        Next
        linedata = Left(linedata, Len(linedata) - 1)
        If rowcounter = rangetoexport.Rows.Count Then
            linedata = "{" & linedata & "}"
        Else
            linedata = "{" & linedata & "},"
        End If
        
        jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
    Next
    linedata = "]}"
    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
    jsonfile.Close
    
    Set fs = Nothing
    
    
End Sub
```

Tendrás que tirar a partir de ahí e ir modificando el código según tus necesidades. O utilizar el código tal cual.